# AngularJS technique for traversing dom smartly resulting in speed optimizations

Tags: performance, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Are there AngularJS technique for traversing and not traversing the DOM during bootstrapping and compiling phase?  I'm trying to prevent angular from looking at certain section elements and all child elements for those sections.  But other sections I do want angular to traverse during the boot phase b/c they have controllers and directives.  Also I'm trying to perform optimization to speed up my page.  I've noticed if I move my "ng-app" directive to only one section it speeds up the page dramatically.

The reason for this is I need to prove that adding something like ngNonBindable directive to certain sections would speed up performance but would prevent angular from walking the DOM for all child nodes in that section.  Also there is really no documentation I could find on ngNonBindable with regard to performance issues.

Also the main reason that the sections need to be ignored is that they may contain tens of thousands of tags that the bootstrap phase has to examine.  Completely ignoring these sections is necessary b/c one of my requirements is not to change existing functionality and to optimize speed of tacked on libraries like AngularJS.

Finally if ngNonBindable is not a good fit for this scenario is there a better directive or technique like creating a directive or returning immediately if a certain section is detected to prevent walking the DOM down that particular section?

Example:

```
<section data-ng-ignore-me>
    <children data-negatory class="negative" value="{negatory}">
     <child attr="1stChild" class="childClass">1st of many</child>... 
    <child ...>10000 more child nodes</child>
  </children>
</section>

<section data-ng-proceed>...
      <ctrl1></ctrl1>
      <ctrl2></ctrl2>
      ...
      <ctrln></ctrln>
      <h3 data-mydirective></h3>
</section.
```

I don't want to move ng-app b/c I want to use angular everywhere and I believe I can only have one ng-app on the page.  So I want to leave ng-app in the html tag.

Comment: Why do you have 10000+ nodes in your DOM? Are they being generated by some server side rendering? Are they actually visible to the user or is there some filtering going on?

Comment: Yes.  There are some legacy reports built in to the existing code and there are some legacy js arrays that are being filtered upon.  And its not a single page app currently.

Comment: If you can do the filtering from angular with `ng-if` or an ng-repeat with an angular filter then this should improve performance as the content that is filtered out will not be added to the dom.